# Database Performance Problems

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm running into some issues with long query times on very basic queries. This is my first time working with a bigger table (12.5 mil rows) and I'm just trying to figure out what might be bottlenecking or what I can do to improve performance. All data is in 1 table.

**Server Specs:**

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Intel Xeon X3430 @ 2.40GHz
4GB RAM
1TB 7200RPM HDD

**Table Information**

**ID** int(10) UN PK AI
**Store** int(2) UN
**Date** datetime
**Register** int(2) UN
**Cashier** int(3) UN
**Department** int(4) UN
**Total** decimal(7,2)
**Customers** int(5) UN
**Items** int(5) UN
**Time** int(5) UN

**Example Queries and Times**

```
SELECT Store, sum(Total)   
FROM sales   
GROUP BY Store
```

*19.56sec*

```
SELECT Date, Register, Customers, Items, Total   
FROM sales  
WHERE Date(Date) = Date('2013-10-22')   
AND Store = 1
```

*9.59sec*

I can certainly provide more information, but is there anything glaringly obvious as to why these are running so slow?

Comment: What are your indexes ? Use `explain` and tell us the result of your select statements.

Comment: It can be slow bacause of indexes, then the my.ini configuration file can also be the problem.

Comment: Instead of the table info you have, add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE sales;` output. It's much more helpful for others to know details about the table structure and indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are 2 glaring issues.  In the first query you have no criteria -- hence you are asking for the entire sales table to be read, grouped and summarized.  The grouping is going to create a temporary table as well.  Hence you will make a table scan and that will be limited to what the hardware can provide in terms of io performance, which is likely your bottleneck.

In the second query you are performing a function on the Date column Date(Date) which means that even if you have an index on Date, it will not be able to utilize that index , so once again you are going to table scan the table.

With that said, you should run explain extended SELECT.... on each query to gain confidence in this assessment.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll have to look into if there is an alternative to Date(Date), and I'll definitely check out explain extended.

Comment: Paste the results of the explain extended into your question: it would help @ypercube and myself understand better your issues.  You might also be able to tune the params on your mysql instance, so those might be helpful.  Are your tables innodb engine?  I'd highly recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

Query 1:

```
SELECT Store, sum(Total)
FROM sales
GROUP BY Store ;
```

Add an index on `(Store, Total)`:

```
ALTER TABLE sales
  ADD INDEX store_total_IX             -- pick a name for the index
    (store, total) ;
```

---

Query 2:

```
SELECT Date, Register, Customers, Items, Total
FROM sales
WHERE Date(Date) = Date('2013-10-22')
AND Store = 1 ;
```

Add an index on `(Store, Date)`:

```
ALTER TABLE sales
  ADD INDEX store_date_IX             -- pick a name for the index
    (store, date) ;
```

and rewrite the query - so the index can be used - as:

```
SELECT Date, Register, Customers, Items, Total
FROM sales
WHERE Date >= '2013-10-22'
  AND Date < '2013-10-22' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND Store = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! After adding the index to the first query, time went down to about 9 seconds. Just getting rid of Date(Date) in the second query and replacing it with your suggestion cut down the query to 1.6 seconds.

Comment: That sounds like very inefficient still. I suggest you check your mysql config. settings.

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can try for second query:
(1)Create index for datetime column.
(2)Use integer instead of datetime, 2013-10-22 => 20131022